# How to avoid Num Lock affecting letter keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

i have a [trust keyboard](https://www.trust.com/it/product/16593-wireless-keyboard-with-mouse) that behaves in an absurd (imho) way.

It's an extended keyboard, with letters, arrows and numeric pad.
With the Num Lock active the numeric pad writes numbers, which is correct, and with Num Lock not active it moves the cursor, which is also correct. 
The issue is that with Num Lock active I can't use the letters keys because i would input -for instance- <kbd>3</kbd> instead of <kbd>L</kbd>. And of course without Num Lock the numeric pad behaves as the exact copy of the arrows and navigation keys (<kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>...).

It's a total nonsense, and i really hope that Trust didn't sell a keyboard with only these two layout option: letters-**arrows**-**arrows** or half_letters/**numbers**-arrows-**numbers**. 
This Num Lock behavior could make sense in a small keyboard without a numeric pad, and I had this behavior in some small notebook, but to me is a really stupid thing with an extended keyboard.

Trust support didn't understand the issue at the first attempts and after they simply told me that the keyboard is probably broken, and this should highlight that you should not trust Trust support.

The keyboard isn't broken, no dents or whatsoever sign of wear, and this is a specific and repeatable "feature" (which could make sense in similar products).

**Question**: how can i have a keyboard with a reasonable layout like all_the_letters-arrows-numbers? I just want to avoid to have duplicate key functions, especially because this happens at the expense of other useful keys.

PS: I've tried the keyboard with three different PCs: a desktop with Win10, a desktop with Win7, and a laptop with Win10. I've installed the official Trust drivers and software. No error and no message, but the same behavior is observed on every PC.